# What is a Star Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*This is in the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it a Star Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Star Words™ | Not Star Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| America | Canada |
| Joe | Jim |
| Olivia | Emily |
| Next | Last |
| Exile | Banishment |
| Bread | Toast |
| Expose | Reveal |
| Fun | Pleasure |
| Magic | Fantasy |
| Essex | Sussex |
| Player | Opponent |
| Silk | Cotton |

CSV version:

```
Star Words™, Not Star Words™
America,Canada
Joe,Jim
Olivia,Emily
Next,Last
Exile,Banishment
Bread,Toast
Expose,Reveal
Fun,Pleasure
Magic,Fantasy
Essex,Sussex
Player,Opponent
Silk,Cotton
```

These aren't the only Star Words™, there are others that exist.

Comment: Are these the only examples of Star Words™, or do many others exist?

Comment: There are others that exist...

Comment: I just ask because most of the other "What is a Word/Phrase" puzzles I've seen have specified that, and I wondered if maybe this one *not* specifying it was a hint. But fair enough.

Comment: Just to let you know, the image says Intermittent Words instead of Star Words.

Comment: What about "Star wars"?

Comment: I would say it is time for a hint.

Comment: OK then :)You may find this puzzle very entertaining. One is the magic number.

Comment: @Kit-Ginevra, if that "magic number" is a hint, then it's better to put it by editing the post as not everyone aware that you gave a hint on comment section :)

Comment: With "pattern" and "word-property" as tags, can it be assumed that the given info on its own is sufficient to solve this, i.e. no external "information" (such as chart-lists etc.) is needed?

Comment: If the answer from hexomino is correct, that would imply that this question also needs the [tag:knowledge] tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Each Star Word is

> The name of a band or singer who had a number one hit in the US Billboard Hot 100

Specific examples

> **America** - *"A Horse With No Name"* - March 25, 1972 
>  **Joe** (featuring Mystikal) - *"Stutter"* - February 24, 2001  
>  50 Cent featuring **Olivia**  - *"Candy Shop"* - March 5, 2005 
>  **Next** - *"Too Close"* - April 25, 1998 
>  **Exile** - *"Kiss You All Over"* - September 30, 1978 
>  **Bread** - *"Make It with You"* - August 22, 1970 
>  **Exposé** - *"Seasons Change"* - February 20, 1988 
>  **Fun** (featuring Janelle Monáe) - *"We Are Young"* - March 17, 2012 
>  **Magic!** - *"Rude"* - July 26, 2014 
>  The **Essex** - *"Easier Said Than Done"* - July 6, 1963 
>  **Player** - *"Baby Come Back"* - January 14, 1978 
>  **Silk** - *"Freak Me"* - May 1, 1993

Note

> We are not including bands or artists which are known by more than just the single word - this is why I think **Jim Croce** is discounted, he is not known as **Jim**.

Comment: awww, I was thinking along the lines of hollywood stars, but couldn't find a connection to everything